# Not able to fire SelectedNodeChanged event for populated TreeView node

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I need to dynamically generate several treeview on my code and I want to be able to load nodes on demand. I have below code structures. My problem is SelectedNodeChanged event for populated TreeView node will not fire. Once you run below code sample, if you expand child node to several level and then click the child node, the label will not show text and the populated nodes collapse. Any idea is appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TreeViewTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private const int Count = 2;
    private string[] codeList = { "th", "os" };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateTree();
    }


    protected void updateTree()
    {

        treePanel.Controls.Clear();
        TreeView[] treeList = new TreeView[Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            var tree = new TreeView();
            tree.ID = "treelist" + i.ToString();

            tree.TreeNodePopulate += TreeBranch_SelectedNodePopulate;
            tree.SelectedNodeChanged += TreeBranch_SelectedNodeChanged;
            string codeName = codeList[i];
            TreeNode codeNode = new TreeNode(codeName, codeName);
            codeNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
            codeNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
            tree.Nodes.Add(codeNode);
            tree.ExpandDepth = 2;
            treePanel.Controls.Add(tree);
            treeList[i] = tree;
        }
    }

    protected void TreeBranch_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeView treeview = (TreeView)sender;
        string text = treeview.SelectedNode.Text;
        Label1.Text = text;
    }


    protected void TreeBranch_SelectedNodePopulate(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadChildNode(e.Node);
    }


    public void LoadChildNode(TreeNode parentNode)
    {
        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode("childNode","childNode");
        parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
        childNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you are declaring treeviews as you shown in `UpdateFilterTreeView` show its complete code.

Comment: I added more code see if that helps.

Comment: Only `SelectedNodeChanged` event is not firing or both?

Comment: Use `treePanel.Controls.Clear();` instead of `treePanel.Dispose();`

Comment: @X-TECH SelectNodeChanged event will not fired only when node was populated

Comment: Have you tried to replace the code with my answer?

Comment: @X-TECH Thanks for following up! I edited my code as your suggestion but it still not working as expected. I edited my post and pasted a code sample that is able to run and replicate my bug. See if you have any insight into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
treePanel.Controls.Clear();
TreeView[] treeList = new TreeView[codebaseCount]; //But I recommend you use List<TreeView> instead of TreeView[];
for (int i = 0; i < codebaseCount; i++)
{
    var tree = new TreeView();
    tree.ID = "treelist" + i.ToString();
    tree.TreeNodePopulate += TreeBranch_SelectedNodePopulate;
    tree.SelectedNodeChanged += TreeBranch_SelectedNodeChanged;
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(newName,newName);
    newNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
    newNode.Expand();
    tree.Nodes.Add(newNode);
    tree.ExpandDepth = 2;
    treePanel.Controls.Add(tree);
    treeList[i] = tree;        
    // more code ...
}
```